# Solving a system with two equations and two variables in a for loop

Tags: matlab, equation, symbolic-math, equation-solving

I would like to solve a system with two equations and two variables.
 `Tau(i)`and  `Roh(i)` are input arrays.

`Tau=[0.91411 0.91433 0.91389 0.91399 0.91511 0.915]`
`Roh=[0.07941 0.07942 0.07952 0.07946 0.07951 0.07947]`

I would like to calculate `R(i)`and `t(i)`for each `i`step (for loop).
I will be glad to have help to solve the equations.
[image]

`Tau(i)-((1-R(i))^2*t(i))/(1-R(i)^2*t(i)^2)==0`
`Roh(i)-R(i)-((1-R(i))^2*R(i)*t(i)^2)/(1-R(i)^2*t(i)^2)==0`

I have tried the following script but I have difficulty to write the proper code to export the data. I get only "sym" which is not a value.

```
function [R,t] = glassair(Tau, Roh)

for i=1:6
    syms R(i) t(i)
     eq1(i)=sym('Tau(i)-((1-R(i))^2*t(i))/(1-R(i)^2*t(i)^2)');
     eq2(i)=sym('Roh(i)-R(i)-((1-R(i))^2*R(i)*t(i)^2)/(1-R(i)^2*t(i)^2)');
     sol(i)=solve(eq1(i),R(i), eq2(i),t(i));

end
end
```

Comment: You posted before something that you tried. Post that now. The best question is a conbination of your previous an this one!

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I added that part as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There where multiple issues with your code.

- Using the `R(i)` syntax with variables, you mixed in symbolic functions. I think here you only have variables. Same with `eq(i)`, this created a symbolic function, not a list of your equations (as you probably intended)
- You called solve with the wrong order of arguments
- You called `solve` with the wrong order of arguments
- Passing a string to `sym` your known constants `Tau` and `Roh` where not substituted, you ended up with 4 unknowns in your equations

.

```
Tau=[0.91411 0.91433 0.91389 0.91399 0.91511 0.915]
Roh=[0.07941 0.07942 0.07952 0.07946 0.07951 0.07947]

syms R t
for i=1:6
eq1=Tau(i)-((1-R)^2*t)/(1-R^2*t^2);
eq2=Roh(i)-R-((1-R)^2*R*t^2)/(1-R^2*t^2);
sol=solve([eq1,eq2]);
allsol(i).R=double(sol.R);
allsol(i).t=double(sol.t);
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much dear Daniel for help and corrections. It works very well. The only challenge was the order of the equations which produces 2 answers but I managed to divide them.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to define the functions once, then use a for loop to get the values.

```
function [R_out,t_out] = glassair(Tau_in, Roh_in)

syms R t Tau Roh
eq1 = Tau-((1-R)^2*t)/(1-R^2*t^2);
eq2 = Roh-R-((1-R)^2*R*t^2)/(1-R^2*t^2);

R_out = zeros(1,6); % Given it will be always 6
t_out = zeros(1,6);

for i=1:6
    Tau = Tau_in(i);
    Roh = Roh_in(i);
    sol = solve( subs( [eq1;eq2] ) );
    R_out(i) = double(sol.R);
    t_out(i) = double(sol.t);
end

end
```

Matlab is very smart in that defines the types for you. When you solve the equations it detects which variables are needed. The zero allocation is for speed up.